# ‟Пограничные” прилагательные между относительными и притяжательными

Tags: untagged

Документ или статья, где прописывается принадлежность, так сказать, ‟пограничных” прилагательных между этими двумя классами, вроде: ‟лисья хитрость”, ‟медвежья услуга”, ‟двойной удар”, ‟лисья стая”.

В статье написано, что ‟цветные карандаши” — качественное, а ‟цветные металлы” — относительное, — так ли это? Разве карандаши могут быть более или менее цветными? Цветные или нет это дихотомия — либо да, либо нет.

Comment: Чем вам не нравится вопрос? Возьмем сочетание ‟медвежья услуга”. С одной стороны, оно имеет такое же значение, что и сочетание ‟вредная услуга”, а с другой стороны, нельзя сказать ‟более медвежья услуга” или ‟менее медвежья услуга”, — так что принадлежность к качественным или притяжательным просто решает какой-то грамотей. Это просто промежуточные вопросы классификации. Но эти люди должны составлять документы с такими пограничными ситуациями, так как иначе понять это просто невозможно. Должен быть либо документ, либо не следует задавать такие вопросы на различных тестах.

Comment: Странное исправление. Вот если что цитата из справочника Розенталя: ‟Если после обобщающего слова (словосочетания) стоят слова как-то, а именно, например, то есть, то перед ними ставится запятая, а после них — двоеточие: ”Сухими болотами называются места, носящие в себе все признаки некогда существовавших болот, как-то: кочки, следы родниковых ям и разные породы болотных трав (Акс.)”.